# Обернуть каждое слово в тег

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли обернуть каждое слово по отдельности в тег ? На примере текста : `Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta` только что бы каждое слово было по отдельности в теге

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".symbols");
var str = container.innerHTML;

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
{
  var e = document.createElement("span");
  e.innerHTML = str[i];
  container.appendChild(e);
}
```

```html
   <div class="symbols">lorem ipsum sit ammet dolar </div>
```

Вот так пробовал - получается обернуть только предложение

Comment: определенно возможно.

Comment: например разбиваешь строку на слова и оборачиваешь каждое, еще вариант - замена с регуляркой

Comment: _получается обернуть только предложение_ - не понял что за предложение, если тут оборачивается каждый символ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Приведенный вами код можно преобразовать к такому виду:

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".symbols");
var arr = container.innerHTML.split(/\s+/);
var str = '';

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if(arr[i]){
        arr[i] = '<span>'+arr[i]+'</span>';
    }
}

container.innerHTML = arr.join(' ');
```

```html
   <div class="symbols">lorem ipsum sit ammet dolar </div>
```

Здесь множественные пробелы учитываются, но не переносятся в окончательный вариант (заменяются одним пробелом).

Answer (score 5):

Например можно так (ES6):

```
str.split(' ').map(s => `<div>${s}</div>`).join(' ')
```

Или, если нет возможности использовать шаблонные строки и arrow-функции:

```
str.split(' ').map(function (s) { return '<div>' + s + '</div>'; }).join(' ');
```

Вообще говоря, точная реализация зависит от контекста.

Comment: если подряд несколько пробелов добавит лишнюю обертку :-)

Comment: у меня в моём примере тоже если есть пробел так же определяется как span - что как раз лишнее

Comment: Ну если несколько подряд, то да, по идее надо по другому разбирать в реальной жизни)

Answer (score 3):

Проблема кода в вопросе в том, что цикл идет *по символам* строки, а не по словам, поэтому оборачивается каждый символ.

Для исправления нужно идти по словам.

Либо, как вариант, воспользоваться методом [*replace* с регулярным выражением](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".symbols");
var str = container.innerHTML;
container.innerHTML = str.replace(/\b[^\s]+?\b/g, $0 => `<span>${$0}</span>`);
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="symbols">Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta</div>
```

Comment: Grundy ты шедевр , я с вас обоих кайфую , почему нельзя выбрать два варианта Лучшими ?

Comment: некорректно обработает небуквенные символы, напр. слеш или дефис

Comment: @Sergiks, ага, посчитает их границей слова