# Есть ли способ перевернуть текст на css?

Tags: css

**мне кажется что для этого использовать js лишнее**

```js
var container = document.querySelector("article p");
var arr = container.innerHTML.split(/\s+/);
var str = '';

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i]) {
    arr[i] = '<span>' + arr[i] + '</span>';
  }
}

container.innerHTML = arr.join(' ');
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
article {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  margin-left: 300px;
}
article span {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

<article>
  <p>
    t e x t - r o t a t i o n
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: обернуть все буквы в span https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/xfp7akox/

Comment: так как у css нет доступа к конкретному символу - без оборачивания каждого символа в отдельный элемент, типа спана, это невозможно. Именно это и делается в js

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://webref.ru/css/writing-mode)

Comment: @soledar10  я так и сделал в js - я так умею , js здесь мне подсказали

Comment: @Grundy если не ошибаюсь то код js ваш , спасибо он мне частенько пригождается - так и реализовал - что бы не захломлять span разметку

Comment: вряд ли мой. я бы скорее replace использовал и текст предварительно пробелами не разбивал. Как-нибудь так: `var arr = container.innerHTML.replace(/./g,"<span>$&</span>");`

Comment: @soledar10 жаль

Comment: @Grundy вроде ваш , вы мне первый кто ответили - и ваш ответ я выбрал лучшим

Comment: @Geyan, не :-) [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555940/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3) я как раз replace предлагал :)

Comment: @Grundy сорри - фигня получается - приму ваш вариант за основу в будущем

Comment: лучше выбирать тот, который лучше для задачи подходит. Там под моим ответом есть небольшие ограничения

Comment: @Grundy я это знаю , ни чего страшного

Comment: @Grundy, всё равно не надо так с innerHTML обращаться...

Comment: @Qwertiy, если там только текст - почему нет? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, а как насчёт текста с мнемониками?

Comment: @Qwertiy, очевидно никак :-) мнемоники разделятся на символы. Кстати, а они разве после присваивания сохраняются? а не заменяются на конкретный символ?

Comment: @Grundy, это ж `innerHTML`. Чтобы был символ, надо читать `textContent`, что для данной задачи, вообще-то логично. Но тогда всё равно косяк, когда символ из текста суётся в html без экранирования. Т. е. в функции замены должна быть обработка как минимум для `<` и `&`.

Comment: @Grundy, добавил правильный вариант разбивания.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно попробовать что-то такое:

```css
article {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 300px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  width: .75em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

<article>
  t e x t - r o t a t i o n
</article>
```

или такое

```css
article {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 300px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  width: .75em;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

<article>
  text-rotation
</article>
```

Comment: ну ты б хоть написал, что из-за пробелов, когда ширина контейнера маленькая - браузер сам перенесет

Comment: @Grundy, можно и без пробелов перенести.

Comment: @Grundy, добавил вариант без пробелов.

Answer (score 9):

Варианты:

```css
.p-1 {
  width:1px;
  -ms-word-break:   break-all;
 
  word-break:       break-word;
  word-wrap:        break-word;
}

.p-2 {
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl; /* old syntax. IE */
-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
-moz-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
-ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* new syntax */
   
-webkit-text-orientation: upright;
   -moz-text-orientation: upright;
    -ms-text-orientation: upright;
        text-orientation: upright;
  
  /* min-height: 500px; */
}


.p-0 i {
  font-style: normal;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  Вариант 1:  
  <p class="p-1">
    t e x t - r o t a t i o n
  </p>


  Вариант 2:
  <p class="p-2">
    t e x t - r o t a t i o n
  </p>
  
 Вариант 3:   
 <p class="p-0">
   <i>t</i>
   <i>e</i>
   <i>x</i>
   <i>t</i>
   <i><br></i>
   <i>r</i>
   <i>o</i>
   <i>t</i>
   <i>a</i>
   <i>t</i>
   <i>e</i>
 </p>
```

[Больше тут](http://generatedcontent.org/post/45384206019/writing-modes)

Comment: Леночка когда здесь как на тостере сделают несколько вариантов выбора правильного ответа ?

Comment: @Geyan боюсь, что не сделают. Все правильные ответы типично получают свою дозу голосов, а галочкой автор отмечает ответ, которым в конечном итоге воспользовался. А если скомбинировал несколько, то это может быть достойно отдельного собственного ответа с галочкой. Если хотите кому-то выдать дополнительный пряник, откройте конкурс, например (мин. 50 репутации на награду). Только имейте в виду, что если захотите выдать несколько наград, каждая следующая должна быть больше предыдущей. Не разоритесь :Р

Comment: @Geyan, у Qwertiy отличный ответ, так что все в порядке)

Comment: @Geyan, правильный ответ - тот, который помог лично вам.

Comment: @D-side этот рейтинг здесь просто циферки и всё, и ни чего кроме большего количества циферок не даёт - потому меня не напрягает что у кого то много циферок а у кого то нет - не жалко

Comment: @D-side но варианты меня устроили все

Comment: @Nofate все помогли - что делать ? Есть здесь те по ком я фанатею , и те кто мне дорог

Comment: @Geyan, с таким расчетом ( "те по ком я фанатею , и те кто мне дорог") выбирать ответ - в корне не верно)))

Comment: И такой вопрос "когда здесь как на тостере сделают несколько вариантов выбора правильного ответа " думаю как раз можно на мете задать.

Comment: @Geyan *рейтинг здесь просто циферки и всё* -- это правильное отношение! Хотя у циферок есть техническая роль, ограничение по привилегиям, и выдать кому-то поощрительных циферок может быть приятно для получателя. Хуже точно не будет. И Елена верно отметила -- это можно обсудить на Мете, если вас это очень интересует.

Comment: Леночка вы не поняли меня , не по критериям , а по вариантам ответов , а всё остальное к слову

Comment: @D-side идея ! Но не для моего уровня

Comment: @Geyan, после 25К рейтинг ничего не даёт, а до - вот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges. Из наиболее интересного - 10К включает [просмотр удалённых сообщений](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: Вариант 2 какой-то сильно сомнительный. У хрома получилось 3 столбца справа налево... Которые ещё и хочется прочитать как "not teax"...

Comment: Это для китайского вообще (если не ошибаюсь), чтобы не было переноса можно задать высоту(закомментриована)

Answer (score 7):

Пример с `writing-mode`. Возможно, вам подойдет. Также есть вариант с `word-break` [здесь](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/).

```css
.my-text {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
.my-text2 {
  line-height: 1;
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Обычный текст
</p>
<p class="my-text">
  Текст по вертикали
</p>
<p>
  Обычный текст
</p>
<p class="my-text2">
  Странный текст
</p>
```

Comment: а буковки ? в примере видите как сделано , я и хотел без span перевернуть , в моём случае на js обёрнуты быквы  в span

Comment: @Geyan я восстановил ответ, чтобы его изменить.

Comment: вы не поняли меня наверно ! буквы повернуты - а надо в нормальном отображении , как положено - в вашем примере повёрнуты буквы

Answer (score 3):

Есть вот такая штука `writing-mode` она поворачивает текст или вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-can-i-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser)

Comment: в сафари проблема с mode

Comment: сами буковки тоже надо повернуть - потому этот вариант не айс

Answer (score 2):

Если делать оборачивание каждого символа в `span`, то правильно его делать так:

```js
var container = document.querySelector("div");

container.innerHTML = container.textContent.replace(/\s+|./g, function (m) {
  return '<span>' + ({'<': '&lt;', '&': '&amp;'}[m] || m) + '</span>';
});
```

```css
span { background: silver; }
span:nth-child(even) { background: antiquewhite; }
```

```html
<div>Cras ultricies ligula    sed magna &lt; dictum && porta</div>
```

В отличие от css'ного варианта, тут можно устроить центрирование символов:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('article');

container.innerHTML = container.textContent.replace(/\s+|./g, function (m) {
  return '<span>' + ({'<': '&lt;', '&': '&amp;'}[m] || m) + '</span>';
});
```

```css
article {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 300px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

<article>
  text-rotation
</article>
```

Comment: тогда уж лучше через appendChild все собрать чтобы не смотреть на эти экранирования :-)

Comment: я запутался, блин вариантов накидали - я обалдел - как все варианты выбрать  ? как на тостере